# Decoding URL in SPIP

Tags: php, spip

I have a search form in SPIP which does a GET to /recherche

Now when I am typing something like `cinéma` the **é** is automatically being encoded to something like `cin%25C3%25A9ma`

In SPIP, if I do

```
<?php echo urldecode($_GET['recherche']; ?>
```

It is being converted back to cinéma.

However, In SPIP, I would retrieve the value of recherche with something like this:

```
#ENV{recherche}
```

Is there someway to decode this variable. Any in-built function in SPIP?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own filter, adding this function in your `mes_fonctions.php` file:

```
function filtre_urldecode($v) {
    return urldecode($v);
}
```

You then can use `[(#ENV{recherche}|urldecode)]` in your squelette.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to decode an URL in SPIP. You have to use PHP's `urldecode()`.

Answer (score 0):

`[(#ENV{recherche}|urldecode)]` will do the job.

For reference, please see [SPIP's filters: Adding your own filters](https://www.spip.net/en_article2465.html#Adding-your-own-filters)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to create a new dedicated SPIP filter, since you can use PHP's `urldecode` as an SPIP filter. For example:

```
[(#ENV{recherche}|urldecode)]
```

Comment: this answer is correct, as other have also  later written

or what's wrong with it ?